# Java JXLS Transformer error

Tags: java, jxls

I'm just trying to prove a demo code from Java JXLS : http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/object_collection.html 
but after adding (without MAVEN) **necessary libraries:**

- jxls-2.3.0.jar
- jxls-poi-1.0.9.jar
- jxls-reader-2.0.2.jar
- poi-3.14-20160307.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar

I get the following error trace:

```
ERROR [org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-9) Method createTransformer of org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer class thrown an Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
        at org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:35) [jxls-2.3.0.jar:]

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:198) [poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar:3.14]
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:170) [poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar:3.14]
        at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:49) [jxls-poi-1.0.9.jar:]
        at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:42) [jxls-poi-1.0.9.jar:]

 ERROR [stderr]  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
```

I've tried all possibilities and always get the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you have conflicting jars in your project.

If you somehow have two versions of POI (ex. 3,14 - 3,06) in your project, it cannot instantiate classes or invoke methods. Check for those conflicts.

(if you use maven please check the dependency hierarchy to see all the dependencies and exclude different versions of poi and try again.)

Answer (score 1):

Tried a lot and solved the issues but adding the below List of dependency JAR used to solve this issue

- commons-codec-1.10.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- jxls-2.4.0.jar
- jxls-jexcel-1.0.6.jar
- jxls-poi-1.0.12.jar
- jxls-reader-2.0.2.jar
- poi-3.14.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.15.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar

Answer (score 0):

To run this example with the current Jxls-2.3.0 release you need the following libraries in your classpath

- jxls-2.3.0.jar
- jxls-poi-1.0.11.jar
- poi-3.14.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.14.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
- commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.2-api.jar

Another option of what you can do is to setup a simple Maven project with jxls dependencies and then use [Copying project dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) goal of Maven Dependency Plugin to download and copy all the dependencies into a separate folder.

The jxls-2.3.0 and earlier versions do not properly display the exception stacktrace when searching for a transformer implementation. 
So now it is difficult to figure out what is wrong with your classpath.
This will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: It does not work anyway. I added the last libraries without result.

Comment: This is a minimal set of libraries that works for me. If it does not work for you get the latest master branch of jxls and use it to build jxls jar. The latest changes contain exception details printed when Transformer cannot be instantiated so you will be able to see more details.

Comment: I got the same error, and I did what @Leonid Vysochyn said, and the error change to `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath`. Could some one tell me what to do in order to work propertly?

Comment: If you compiled the latest master branch you will see the exception stack trace with a detail message.